# how to save data on database on cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I wanna save some data on database in cakephp. 
here is my code...

```
public function addout()

{
    $uid = $this->Auth->User()['id'];

    $out = $this->Outs->newEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $out = $this->Outs->patchEntity($out, $this->request->data);

        $this->request->data['user_id'] = $uid;

    }
        if ($this->Outs->save($out)) {

            $this->Flash->success(__('The out has been saved.'));


        } else {

            $this->Flash->error(__('The out could not be saved. Please, try again.'));

        }


}
```

and here is my template

```
   <?php

echo $this->Form->create();

echo $this->Form->input('out time:', array('class' => 'outtime', 'id' => 'outtime', 'name' => 'outtime' ));

echo $this->Form->input('out date  :', array('class' => 'datepicker0', 'id' => 'outdate', 'name' => 'outdate', 'type' => 'text'));

echo $this->Form->input('return date:', array('class' => 'datepicker0', 'id' => 'returndate', 'name' => 'returndate', 'type' => 'text'));

echo $this->Form->input('distance :', array('class' => 'distance', 'id' => 'distance', 'name' => 'distance', 'type' => 'textarea'));

echo $this->Form->input('phone number:', array('class' => 'phonenumber', 'id' => 'phonenumber', 'name' => 'phonenumber', 'type' => 'text'));


echo $this->Form->button(__('submit'));
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

but when I run it out put is:The out could not be saved. Please, try again.
 my database is ...
[image: table]

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call method errors() on entity  `$out->errors()` to see validations errors

```
 if ($this->Outs->save($out)) {
   $this->Flash->success(__('The out has been saved.'));
 } else {
    debug($out->errors()); die;
    $this->Flash->error(__('The out could not be saved. Please, try again.'));

 }
```